# Grass growing over text - Gradient growth?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I made this simple render with some grass growing on some text. I would however like to make the growth start at one side and then spread, preferably with some sort of gradient. As it is now it grows everywhere at the same time.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13VuFb1lYPRAhrykHtWadldaN3yHeX1OU/view?usp=sharing

So far it is just a scatter of objects that has a size value increase. Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to achieve this effect?

Is it possible to make the size value of the grass increase by the proximity of another hidden object? Or is it possible with *Geometry Nodes*, with which I have no experience...

Comment: PS: You did everything right ;-) Next time it would be handy if you attach your blend file right away, so we can show the solution using your example: https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

You can solve this as follows:

[image]

Here the node `Gradient Texture` is used as a base for creating the gradual gradient.

1. First create your letters (however you want to do it) and distribute the points for the instantiation of the objects on them with `Distribute Points on Faces`.
2. Then grab the X-positions of the points and scale these values. The node `Gradient Texture` creates a gradient between $0$ and $1$, and thus you fit the values into this range. Depending on how smooth you want the transition to be, you can make different calculations here.
3. Then use the current frame and a value for the velocity to create a vector for the node `Gradient Texture`.
4. After that you have to use `Map Range` to bring the obtained values into a range that serves as scaling. Here you can also try different values for *To Min* and *To Max*, because this also produces a nice result.
5. Finally you use `Instance on Points`, take the *Rotation* from your previously created points and finally apply the scaling.

---

Another possibility would be to use an *Empty* or other object with which you control the scaling of the points:

[image]

Here I use the node `Geometry Proximity` to evaluate the distance to the points.

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.1+)*</sub>

Comment: I tried and made it work on the file you provided, but I cant seam to recreate when I started a new file. This is regarding the use of Geometry Proximity. What am I doing wrong here, @quellenform ?

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=79vl8B09" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/79vl8B09/)

Comment: @Rosa You've built this up perfectly right anyway, congratulations! But take a closer look at the node `Map Range` and the values for *To Min* and *To Max*, they should be different of course.